# Rails Performing IN Operation

Tags: sql, database, ruby-on-rails-3

Might get grief, but here it comes.

I am trying to execute an IN operation on one of my clauses in Rails.

The call is:

```
@ret = BBOrder.find(:all, :conditions => ["symbol LIKE ? AND creationDateTimeInt IN ?", "%#{symbol}%", "#{date_ints}"])
```

`date_ints` are created before as an array, then have a `join.(', ')` on them. I tried to just input a single value, to test the operation

The error message is:

```
 BBOrder Load (2.2ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [dbo].[BBOrders].* FROM [dbo].[BBOrders] WHERE (symbol LIKE N''%%'' AND creationDateTimeInt IN N''(20130616)'')'
ODBC::Error: 37000 (102) [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '(20130616)'.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [dbo].[BBOrders].* FROM [dbo].[BBOrders] WHERE (symbol LIKE N''%%'' AND creationDateTimeInt IN N''(20130616)'')'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 26ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (ODBC::Error: 37000 (102) [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '(20130616)'.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [dbo].[BBOrders].* FROM [dbo].[BBOrders] WHERE (symbol LIKE N''%%'' AND creationDateTimeInt IN N''(20130616)'')'):
  app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:43:in `home'
```

Any ideas?

And I don't want to do make raw SQL queries. That will just bulk up the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@ret = BBOrder.find(:all, :conditions => ["symbol LIKE ? AND creationDateTimeInt IN(?)", "%#{symbol}%", date_ints])
```

You don't need to do the string parsing for the IN value and I think you need the brackets.

Comment: ODBC::Error: 22005 (245) [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '20130618, 20130617, 20130616, 20130615, 20130614, 20130613, 20130612, 20130611, 20130610' to data type int.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT [dbo].[BBOrders].* FROM [dbo].[BBOrders] WHERE (symbol LIKE N''%%'' AND creationDateTimeInt IN(N''20130618, 20130617, 20130616, 20130615, 20130614, 20130613, 20130612, 20130611, 20130610''))'

Comment: This method worked for. Addition - Do not use .join on your array. Leave it as it is and just pass in the array itself. Rails will handle it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Rails 3 you can use the AR query interface like this:

```
BBOrder.where('symbol LIKE ?', "%#{symbol}%").where(creationDateTimeInt: date_ints)
```

More here [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Comment: This yields the same result

Comment: It's maybe because of the LIKE statement